# SKLearn Linear Regression but setting certain coefficients before starting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'd like to run a linear regression using SKLearn on a dataset with say 50 variables. However, I'd like to set the coefficients for say 2 of the variables before it starts training. Is that possible?

Comment: When you write "set", do you mean they are fixed?  I.e., you don't want any training to alter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to provide an initial value or guess for the coefficients, and this is not possible for `LinearRegression` because it [calls scipy.linalg.lstsq from scipy](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L594).

Not very sure what is the purpose for providing initial guess because for linear regression, you can fit the model, that is find the least square solution by using QR decomposition or SVD, there's no need to provide an initial guess or so.

If you want to try it for some purpose, I think you can try something like [lsmr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr) or [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), but bear in mind, it's not really the commonly known linear regression from here:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, y = datasets.load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X,y)

regr.coef_
array([ -0.47623169, -11.40703082,  24.72625713,  15.42967916,
       -37.68035801,  22.67648701,   4.80620008,   8.422084  ,
        35.73471316,   3.21661161])

#lmsr
lsmr(X,y,x0 = np.repeat(2.0,X.shape[1]))
(array([ -0.4762317 , -11.40703083,  24.72625712,  15.42967915,
        -37.68035803,  22.67648699,   4.8062001 ,   8.42208398,
         35.73471314,   3.21661159])

#non linear least square
def func(x,*params):
    return x @ params

coef_, cov_ = curve_fit(func,X,y,p0 = np.repeat(2,X.shape[1]))
coef_

array([ -0.47623371, -11.40702964,  24.72625986,  15.42967394,
       -37.68022801,  22.67639202,   4.8061298 ,   8.42205138,
        35.73466837,   3.21661273])
```